# AxisError: axis2: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

Tags: python-3.x

import random

## from skimage import io

import numpy as np
from glob import glob
import SimpleITK as sitk
from keras.utils import np_utils

class Pipeline(object):

```
def __init__(self, list_train ,Normalize=True):
    self.scans_train = list_train
    self.train_im=self.read_scans(Normalize)


def read_scans(self,Normalize):

    train_im=[]
    for i in range(len( self.scans_train)):
        if i%10==0:
            print('iteration [{}]'.format(i))

        flair = glob( self.scans_train[i] + '/*_flair.nii.gz')
        t2 = glob( self.scans_train[i] + '/*_t2.nii.gz')
        gt = glob( self.scans_train[i] + '/*_seg.nii.gz')
        t1 = glob( self.scans_train[i] + '/*_t1.nii.gz')
        t1c = glob( self.scans_train[i] + '/*_t1ce.nii.gz')

        t1s=[scan for scan in t1 if scan not in t1c]

        if (len(flair)+len(t2)+len(gt)+len(t1s)+len(t1c))<5:
            print("there is a problem here!!! the problem lies in this patient :", self.scans_train[i])
            continue
        scans = [flair[0], t1s[0], t1c[0], t2[0], gt[0]]

        #read a volume composed of 4 modalities
        tmp = [sitk.GetArrayFromImage(sitk.ReadImage(scans[k])) for k in range(len(scans))]

        #crop each volume to have a size of (146,192,152) to discard some unwanted background and thus save some computational power ;)
        z0=1
        y0=29
        x0=42
        z1=147
        y1=221  
        x1=194  
        tmp=np.array(tmp)
        tmp=tmp[:,z0:z1,y0:y1,x0:x1]

        #normalize each slice
        if Normalize==True:
            tmp=self.norm_slices(tmp)

        train_im.append(tmp)
        del tmp    
    return  np.array(train_im)


def sample_patches_randomly(self, num_patches, d , h , w ):

    '''
    INPUT:
    num_patches : the total number of samled patches
    d : this correspnds to the number of channels which is ,in our case, 4 MRI modalities
    h : height of the patch
    w : width of the patch
    OUTPUT:
    patches : np array containing the randomly sampled patches
    labels : np array containing the corresping target patches
    '''
    patches, labels = [], []
    count = 0

    #swap axes to make axis 0 represents the modality and axis 1 represents the slice. take the ground truth
    gt_im = np.swapaxes(self.train_im, 0, 1)[4]   

    #take flair image as mask
    msk = np.swapaxes(self.train_im, 0, 1)[0]
    #save the shape of the grounf truth to use it afterwards
    tmp_shp = gt_im.shape

    #reshape the mask and the ground truth to 1D array
    gt_im = gt_im.reshape(-1).astype(np.uint8)
    msk = msk.reshape(-1).astype(np.float32)

    # maintain list of 1D indices while discarding 0 intensities
    indices = np.squeeze(np.argwhere((msk!=-9.0) & (msk!=0.0)))
    del msk

    # shuffle the list of indices of the class
    np.random.shuffle(indices)

    #reshape gt_im
    gt_im = gt_im.reshape(tmp_shp)

    #a loop to sample the patches from the images
    i = 0
    pix = len(indices)
    while (count<num_patches) and (pix>i):
        #randomly choose an index
        ind = indices[i]
        i+= 1
        #reshape ind to 3D index
        ind = np.unravel_index(ind, tmp_shp)
        # get the patient and the slice id
        patient_id = ind[0]
        slice_idx=ind[1]
        p = ind[2:]
        #construct the patch by defining the coordinates
        p_y = (p[0] - (h)/2, p[0] + (h)/2)
        p_x = (p[1] - (w)/2, p[1] + (w)/2)
        p_x=list(map(int,p_x))
        p_y=list(map(int,p_y))

        #take patches from all modalities and group them together
        tmp = self.train_im[patient_id][0:4, slice_idx,p_y[0]:p_y[1], p_x[0]:p_x[1]]
        #take the coresponding label patch
        lbl=gt_im[patient_id,slice_idx,p_y[0]:p_y[1], p_x[0]:p_x[1]]

        #keep only paches that have the desired size
        if tmp.shape != (d, h, w) :
            continue
        patches.append(tmp)
        labels.append(lbl)
        count+=1
    patches = np.array(patches)
    labels=np.array(labels)
    return patches, labels



def norm_slices(self,slice_not): 
    '''
        normalizes each slice , excluding gt
        subtracts mean and div by std dev for each slice
        clips top and bottom one percent of pixel intensities
    '''
    normed_slices = np.zeros(( 5,146, 192, 152)).astype(np.float32)
    for slice_ix in range(4):
        normed_slices[slice_ix] = slice_not[slice_ix]
        for mode_ix in range(146):
            normed_slices[slice_ix][mode_ix] = self._normalize(slice_not[slice_ix][mode_ix])
    normed_slices[-1]=slice_not[-1]

    return normed_slices    



def _normalize(self,slice):
    '''
        input: unnormalized slice 
        OUTPUT: normalized clipped slice
    '''
    b = np.percentile(slice, 99)
    t = np.percentile(slice, 1)
    slice = np.clip(slice, t, b)
    image_nonzero = slice[np.nonzero(slice)]
    if np.std(slice)==0 or np.std(image_nonzero) == 0:
        return slice
    else:
        tmp= (slice - np.mean(image_nonzero)) / np.std(image_nonzero)
        #since the range of intensities is between 0 and 5000 ,the min in the normalized slice corresponds to 0 intensity in unnormalized slice
        #the min is replaced with -9 just to keep track of 0 intensities so that we can discard those intensities afterwards when sampling random patches
        tmp[tmp==tmp.min()]=-9
        return tmp
```

'''
def save_image_png (img,output_file="img.png"):
    """
    save 2d image to disk in a png format
    """
    img=np.array(img).astype(np.float32)
    if np.max(img) != 0:
        img /= np.max(img)   # set values < 1
    if np.min(img) <= -1: # set values > -1
        img /= abs(np.min(img))
    io.imsave(output_file, img)
'''

def concatenate ():

```
'''
concatenate two parts into one dataset
this can be avoided if there is enough RAM as we can directly from the whole dataset
'''
Y_labels_2=np.load("y_dataset_second_part.npy").astype(np.uint8)
X_patches_2=np.load("x_dataset_second_part.npy").astype(np.float32)
Y_labels_1=np.load("y_dataset_first_part.npy").astype(np.uint8)
X_patches_1=np.load("x_dataset_first_part.npy").astype(np.float32)

#concatenate both parts
X_patches=np.concatenate((X_patches_1, X_patches_2), axis=0)
Y_labels=np.concatenate((Y_labels_1, Y_labels_2), axis=0)
del Y_labels_2,X_patches_2,Y_labels_1,X_patches_1

#shuffle the whole dataset
shuffle = list(zip(X_patches, Y_labels))
np.random.seed(138)
np.random.shuffle(shuffle)
X_patches = np.array([shuffle[i][0] for i in range(len(shuffle))])
Y_labels = np.array([shuffle[i][1] for i in range(len(shuffle))])
del shuffle


np.save( "x_training",X_patches.astype(np.float32) )
np.save( "y_training",Y_labels.astype(np.uint8))
#np.save( "x_valid",X_patches_valid.astype(np.float32) )
#np.save( "y_valid",Y_labels_valid.astype(np.uint8))
```

if **name** == '**main**':

```
#Paths for Brats2017 dataset
path_HGG = glob('Brats2017/Brats17TrainingData/HGG/**')
path_LGG = glob('Brats2017/Brats17TrainingData/LGG/**')
path_all=path_HGG+path_LGG

#shuffle the dataset
np.random.seed(2022)
np.random.shuffle(path_all)

np.random.seed(1555)
start=0
end=20
#set the total number of patches
#this formula extracts approximately 3 patches per slice
num_patches=146*(end-start)*3
#define the size of a patch
h=128
w=128 
d=4 

pipe=Pipeline(list_train=path_all[start:end],Normalize=True)
Patches,Y_labels=pipe.sample_patches_randomly(num_patches,d, h, w)

#transform the data to channels_last keras format
Patches=np.transpose(Patches,(0,2,3,1)).astype(np.float32)

# since the brats2017 dataset has only 4 labels,namely 0,1,2 and 4 as opposed to previous datasets 
# this transormation is done so that we will have 4 classes when we one-hot encode the targets
Y_labels[Y_labels==4]=3

#transform y to one_hot enconding for keras  
shp=Y_labels.shape[0]
Y_labels=Y_labels.reshape(-1)
Y_labels = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_labels).astype(np.uint8)
Y_labels=Y_labels.reshape(shp,h,w,4)

#shuffle the whole dataset
shuffle = list(zip(Patches, Y_labels))
np.random.seed(180)
np.random.shuffle(shuffle)
Patches = np.array([shuffle[i][0] for i in range(len(shuffle))])
Y_labels = np.array([shuffle[i][1] for i in range(len(shuffle))])
del shuffle

print("Size of the patches : ",Patches.shape)
print("Size of their correponding targets : ",Y_labels.shape)

#save to disk as npy files
#np.save( "x_dataset_first_part",Patches )
#np.save( "y_dataset_first_part",Y_labels)
```

Here i get a AxisError: axis2: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
at  this line  "return bound(*args, **kwds)"
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk6S7.png)

Comment: Please provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ... and the full traceback; it contains lots of useful information.

Comment: Full traceback was attached with my post......Click on the Error then you can see

Comment: I am getting the same error. let's me know too when you get the answer to solve this issue. Thanks